# java - Поднять регистр букв у первого символа строки

Tags: java, строки

Собственно, суть в вопросе. Например, есть строка

```
String old = "геннадий";
```

Нужно получить строку Геннадий, то есть первый символ должен подняться в регистре

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Вариант №1:**

```
String capitalized = old.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + old.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

**Вариант №2:**

```
String capitalized = Character.toUpperCase(old.charAt(0)) + old.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

**Вариант №3:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(old.toLowerCase());
sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)));
String capitalized = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Great solution :)

Answer (score 4):

**Вариант 4:**

Используйте [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

```
String capitalized = WordUtils.capitalize(old);
```

для капитализации всего предложения, или

```
String capitalized = StringUtils.capitalize(old);
```

для капитализации одного слова.

Comment: Зачем? Библиотеки эти делают программирование легким, да. Но для такой цели? Не вижу смвсла

Comment: 1. Если подключите Commons Lang к своему проекту, наверняка найдёте ещё много мест, где можно классы из этой библиотеки использовать в вашем коде.  2. Это всего лишь ещё один варинт

Comment: Забыл ещё упомянуть, что Commons Lang корректно обрабатывает null и пустые строки, а при использовании вариантов 1-3 вам придётся контролировать это самостоятельно.